# Как выполнить команду при нахождении записи в логе

Tags: linux, bash

Я использую вот такую конструкцию

```
tail -f -n 1 ./server.log| grep -m 1 'search pattern' ; kill %1
```

Но проблема в том что server.log ротируется раз в час, следовально создается новый дискриптор, а тайл читает старый, в общем нужно каждый час перезапускать. Как избежать зависания tail ? Или что можно использовать вместо него? Или может есть какие то другие способы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте опцию `-F`:

```
tail -F --retry -n 1 ./server.log| grep -m 1 'search pattern' ; kill %1
```

Это заставит `tail` переоткрыт файл, если файл пересоздали/ротировали.

Из man-а:

> The -F option implies the -f option, but tail will also check to see if the file being followed has been renamed or rotated.  The file is
> closed and reopened when tail detects that the filename being read from has a new inode number.

Comment: tail -F --retry -n 1 ./server.log
рабочий вариант получился в итоге